How to make the column width of table fixed?
I would like to make the column width of table fixed, with a text in the middle of the middle cell.
Neither of the two ways I tried in the minimal working example works. (the first one achieves fixed width but the text is not in the center, while the second one makes the text middle but the middle column is too wide.) I appreciate your help.
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabls}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                             {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{...}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
                   &  \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{$a$}                     &                      
\end{tabular}
\hskip 15mm
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
                   & $b$                      &                      
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{frame}


\end{document}


Hm, first you prescribe columns widths by p{1cm} and than overwrite by \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} (I suppose that you like to have \multicolumn{1}{c|}{})? which has not prescribed width but width od cell content ... What is purpose of letter below table? Is this some sort of caption?

You neither need [h] nor \begin{center}...\end{center}. Tables don't float in beamer and are centred by default.


I would like to make the column width of table fixed, with a text in the middle of the middle cell. Neither of the two ways I tried in the minimal working example works. The first one achieves fixed width but the text is not in the center, while the second one makes the text middle but the middle column is too wide.

To center-set the labels $a$ and $b$ below the respective three-column tabular environments, you should change
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{$a$} &                      

and
& $b$ &       

in the final rows of the tabular environments to
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$a$}   

and
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$b$}

That way, the centering is performed across the entire width of the respective tabular environment. Note: There should be no & symbols in either row after making this change.
Two additional observations:

LaTeX table and figure floats are disabled in beamer documents. No need to incur the float-associated overhead in a beamer document.

If you need vertical framelines in tabular environments, don't specify \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}} and \begin{tabular}{lll}, respectively, followed by a multitude of \multicolumn{1} statements. Instead, just write \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{p{1cm}|}} and \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}, respectively, and get rid of all \multirow{1} wrappers.



\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] % '[t]' is optional

\frametitle{Two tabular environments} % the caption for both tables

\centering

\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{p{1cm}|}}
\hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(a)} 
\end{tabular}
\hspace{15mm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
 u & v & w \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(b)} 
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}


To long for comment ...
It is not entirely clear what you after. A table with column width of 1cm where contents in cells, if exist, are centered? Like as shown in the following picture:

Above image is generated by following MWE:
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Y}, vline{1-Z}={1-Y}{},
             colspec = {*{3}{Q[c, wd=1cm]}}
             }
    &   &   \\ 
    &   &   \\  
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
    & a &                      
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Y}, vline{1-Z}={1-Y}{},
             colspec = {*{3}{Q[c, wd=1cm]}}
             }
 1      & 2         & 3         \\ 
 44     &   55      & 66        \\  
777 11  & 888 22    & 999 33    \\
        &           &           \\
    & b &                      
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

However, if letters a and b has function of tables' captions, why you not use \caption instruction for this?
Edit:
Or alternatively when last row is multicolumn row in math mode:
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Y}, vline{1-Z}={1-Y}{},
             colspec = {*{3}{Q[c, wd=1cm]}},
             cell{Z}{1} = {c=3}{$}
             }
    &   &   \\ 
    &   &   \\  
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
a   &   &                      
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Or, my guessing is wrong and you are after for something else?
